# How to implement deep linking in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, html, xml, windows-phone-8, deep-linking

I am trying to implement deep linking using myapp:// moniker. For testing purpose I have an HTML page with the following meta:

```
<html><head>
<meta property="al:windows_phone:app_id_here" content="12345" />
<meta property="al:windows_phone:url" content="myapp://products/?id=widget" />
<meta property="al:windows_phone:myapp" content="Example Store" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And in WMAppManifest, I have declared the protocol as:

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myapp" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

I have hosted the html on a private server but navigating to the page through Internet Explorer on Windows Phone doesn't open the app, instead, it just shows the webpage. I am very new to deep linking. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @chris-w it is xaml... WMAppManifest is xaml file

Comment: It's not XAML amigo, it's [XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), there's a significant difference. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppLinks meta tags do only advertise your deep links to crawlers/bots (so that e.g. Google knows that your website has a corresponding app and deep links).

To implement the actual deep linking you have to add some code to your website. The following is a very barebones example:

```
<script>
  // when the page is loaded...
  window.onload = function() {

    // and viewed on a Windows Phone...
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/)) {

      // then try to open the deep link
      window.location.replace('myapp://products/?id=widget');

      // if it didn't work after half a second, then redirect the
      // user to the app store where he can download the app
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.replace('http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=12345');
      }, 500);
    }
  }
</script>
```

If you do not want to implement it by yourself then you can use a 3rd party provider for deep links, e.g. [Shortcut Media](http://shortcutmedia.com) (Disclaimer: I currently work at Shortcut Media).

Comment: Thanks a lot. The AppLinks documentation doesn't say anything about adding any code to the website. I was hoping this could work just as it does in Android and iOS. Is it possible in any way?? I mean without adding script to the website!!

Comment: You also need to add code to the website for Android and iOS (at least  to support deep links with custom URL schemes)... AppLinks is just a protocol that describes how to publish and navigate deep links, you have to do the actual implementation yourself or use a 3rd party framework (see http://applinks.org/documentation/#implementations)...