# deeplink into internal page windows phone using third party

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, deep-linking, applinks

I have an app made in xamarin (for Android, iOS and Windows Phone) which requires deep linking which should open and internal page on receiving an url.

This url will be sent by sms to the user with http protocol. I tried the solutions provided by [OneLink](https://www.appsflyer.com/onelink/) and [Branch Metrics](https://branch.io/) and they work with Android and iOS. The only problem is with Windows phone (8.1).

Both of them are not able to detect if windows phone is installed and if yes open the app and not take to the store.

Is there any solution to this (maybe third party solution).

NOTE: i have tried directly clicking myapp://open and it works on windows phone but what i need is using http and not my app as the above custom protocols are non clickable within Sms's.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deep linking is possible on Windows Phone. [Shortcut Media](http://shortcut.sc) offers a third-party solution for this (disclaimer: I work for Shortcut Media).

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33564208/211060) to see how to implement it manually...